# Is it possible to run an Appcelerator Titanium applicatin in web browser like Flex?

Tags: browser, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to share code between mobile and web versions of an application created with Appcelerator Titanium? I want to create a mobile application but I also want my users accessing the app using desktop Internet browser, like Flex application can be run in Flash Player or AIR. Is it possible to share code between mobile and web versions of the app?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta or pre release version of a web sdk that will support that functionality. Will try and track down the link, certain it can be found on the Appcelerator developer blog